# Проблема с автоматическим добавлением слеша в url

Tags: nginx

> Nginx + PHP-FPM

Конфиг вирт. хоста:

```
listen 80; 

server_name test.local;
root        /home/httpdocs/test.local/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

access_log  /home/httpdocs/test.local/log/access.log;
error_log   /home/httpdocs/test.local/log/error.log;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/httpdocs/test.local/www/;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/httpdocs/test.local/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED /home/httpdocs/test.local/www/$fastcgi_script_name;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}

location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny  all;
}
```

при открытии url: **test.local** в браузере, происходит автоматический редирект на **test.local/** (добавляет в конце слеш), вот это проблема!

Подскажите, как решить?

p.s.: Хотя при **test.local/post/** автоматически редиректит на **test.local/post** (убирает в конце слеш), что правильно. Т.е. проблема возникает, именно когда в url только имя хоста.

Comment: Проблема была в названии хоста. Переименовал хост на test.local.ru и все нормально стало работать, мда, странно.

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, что даже если вы видите в браузере `example.com`, на самом деле это всегда `example.com/`. Пустого пути не может быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При открытии `test.local` никакого редиректа не происходит. Ваш браузер на самом деле отправляет запрос на `http://test.local/`, просто в некоторых случаях браузер для вашего удобства не отображает в адресной строке `http://` в начале и `/` (если путь состоит из одного лишь `/`) в конце. Видимо, в вашем браузере для доменов вида `example.local` и `example.ru` правила скрытия единственного слеша отличаются.

Как правильно сказал @AlexeyTen, после домена всегда должен быть указан путь, состоящий хотя бы из слеша, пустого пути не бывает.